# Flex 4 Itemrenderer Update Event?

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, apache-flex, listview, flex4

I have a `<s:List>` in my Flex 4.6 project which uses an itemrenderer. My application occasionally pushes more items onto this `<s:List>`, and the itemrenderer obtains and applies this change as expected. My list looks like this:

```
<s:List borderVisible="false" contentBackgroundAlpha="0" 
        dataProvider="{this.data.root.item}" id="reviews"
        itemRenderer="renderers.pages.ReviewRenderer" minHeight="1"
        top="10" width="100%">
  <s:layout>
    <s:VerticalLayout gap="35" requestedMinRowCount="1" useVirtualLayout="false/>
  </s:layout>
</s:List>
```

... and I append more data onto the data provider object like so:

```
this.data.root.item.addItem(this.form.reviewData);
```

I would like to know if there is an event that I can listen for whenever the `addItem()` method pushes more data onto the object for the `<s:List>` to display.

I know I could use the `FlexEvent.VALUE_COMMIT` event, but, according to the documentation, this would dispatch whenever data is first applied to the list, and any item user interaction with the list updates one of its properties (such as selecting one of the list items).

So, just to be clear, I am looking for an event that is dispatched only whenever `addItem()` appends data to the data provider.

**Note:** I am using a `<s:List>` component for a web project, not the mobile optimized version.

Thank you for your time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the `dataProvider` (`this.data.root.item` in your example) to the list is an `ArrayCollection`, `XMLListCollection`, or `ListCollectionView` it will dispatch `CollectionEvent.COLLECTION_CHANGE` when ever the collection changes.

[CollectionEvent](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/mx/events/CollectionEvent.htm) has a `kind` property that you need to inspect, as there are various kinds of changes (see the [CollectionEventKind](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/mx/events/CollectionEventKind.html) class). In particular, you might be interested in `CollectionEventKind.ADD`.

Another approach would be to override the `addItem()` method of your dataProvider and dispatch your own "itemAdded" event:

```
override public function addItem(item:Object):void
{
    super.addItem(item);
    dispatchEvent(new Event("itemAdded"));
}
```

Comment: Fantastic!!! I guess I was looking at this from the wrong end. Let me apply this, and I'll be back to accept. :D